# What's the use of a unique index?

Tags: sql, indexing, unique-constraint

This may be a very silly question, but I have never used unique indexes: I have used unique constraints, though.

I read the related question [Unique index vs. unique constraint that uses a unique index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32654918/unique-index-vs-unique-constraint-that-uses-a-unique-index) but still can't really understand why unique indexes exist.

To me *UNIQUE* sounds more like a constraint than as an index. Shouldn't it always be specified as a constraint? Or am I missing something here? (most likely). So in simple words the question I have is:

- What's the use of a unique index?

Maybe the answer lies in history books and is related on how they were chronologically developed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unique index or unique key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3794607/unique-index-or-unique-key)

Answer (score 3):

One thing a unique index can do that a unique constraint cannot is given in the [PostgreSQL documentation on unique constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/ddl-constraints.html).

> A uniqueness restriction covering only some rows cannot be written as a unique constraint, but it is possible to enforce such a restriction by creating a unique partial index.

In their [partial unique index docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/indexes-partial.html) they give an example.

> Suppose that we have a table describing test outcomes. We wish to ensure that there is only one "successful" entry for a given subject and target combination, but there might be any number of "unsuccessful" entries. Here is one way to do it:
>
> `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tests_success_constraint ON tests (subject, target)
>       WHERE success;`

Comment: Wow, very interesting. Though, not a standad feature by any means, it seems that indexes are (have been) more tweakable than constraints.

Comment: @TheImpaler `create index` is not part of the SQL standard at all. Indexes are not part of the standard, I assume they consider them an implementation detail.

Answer (score 2):

In general, unique constraints are implemented using unique indexes (as far as I know, regardless of database).  The differences between the two are pretty minor -- often having to do only with the name of the constraint in the event of a constraint violation.  Some databases let you choose the type of index for a unique index, so that would be another slight difference.

Why do the two exist?  I can speculate.  The designers of SQL could pretty much agree that the only reasonable way to implement a unique constraint is via a unique index.  Given that `CREATE INDEX` already existed, why not simply allow a unique option as well?  After all, the database would need to support the ability to create a unique index.

Comment: So, indexes may be more tweakable: that's a good point. And yeah, the answer may be historical.

Comment: "*The designers of SQL...*" the designers of SQL did not address indexes at all. `create index` is not part of the standard.